# Why is present continuous used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tense, present-tense

I've just read this sentence in a medic book: *"How do we know when **someone is suffering** from concussion?"*
Would it be incorrect if I used the Present Simple form? For example, *"...when **someone suffers** from concussion?"*

Is there any rule that says that we should use Present Continuous in these types of sentences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two sentences have different meanings, and the simple present version would be incorrect in this context.

*Present continuous* generally means something that is currently true, so if you have a patient and they **are suffering** from a concussion, it means right now. So the question, "*How do we know when someone **is suffering** from concussion?*" means, "*How do we identify that a patient is currently suffering from concussion?*". The answer to this question is a list of symptoms that present when a person **is currently suffering** from a concussion.

*Simple present* generally means something that happens regularly, from time to time, and not necessarily now, so if you have a patient and they **suffer** from concussion, it means from time to time. So the question, "*How do we know when someone **suffers** from concussion?*" means, "*How do we identify that a patient regularly suffers concussions?*". The answer to this question is a list of symptoms of people who **regularly suffer** concussions.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not be incorrect

when **someone suffers** from concussion

you may use both cases, either the verb suffer, like above or the gerund **is suffering** like in the article

Comment: In the original sentence, "suffering", is not a gerund but the present participle of the verb "suffer" in the present continous form. *He/she/it **is suffering***. If the verb is the subject of the sentence  the personal pronoun is not needed, e.g "*The suffering of losing one's child* [it] never leaves."